# How can I restore default chown permissions on a default directory?

Tags: apache2, lamp, raspberry-pi3

How to restore the default chown permissions on a default directory after installation of LAMP web server on my Raspberry pi? and how can I completely remove the LAMP web server?

Answer (score 0):

1. chown changes ownership, not permissions. I dont know what you mean be default directory, but I would guess you mean the /var/www directory. To reset ownership to some default state, you could set it to the user owning your webserver. Normally www-data. Run ps aux | grep apache and check the user running apache. Afterwards set the directory owner to that user: chown -R user:group /var/www (probably chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www)
2. Complete removal is done by using the --purge flag: apt-get remove --purge apache2

If your webserver is not apache, just substitute apache with whatever server you are using. Eg ps aux | grep nginx